# How do I do a set timer within each react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, settimeout

I am making a quiz and I want each question to have a 60-second timer. I am using `react-router` so that users can navigate between questions.

Here is the reusable question Component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
class Questions extends Component { 
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        let { 
            questionCover,
            answerSelection,
            answer1, 
            answer2, 
            answer3, 
            answer4, 
            answer5,
            answer6,
            nextQuestion,
            title1,
            title2,
            back,
            questionNumber,
            selected,         
        } = this.props;

        return(  
        <div>
            <div className="questionContainer">
                <div className="question" id={questionCover} >
                    <h1>{title1.toUpperCase()}</h1>
        { true && <h1>{title2}</h1> }
                </div>
                <div className="answerContainer">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div 
                            id={answer1}
                            className={`answers ${selected === 1 ? 'selected' : ''}`} 
                            onClick={()=> 
                                this.props.selectedScore(1, questionNumber)
                            }
                            >
                        </div>
                        <div 
                            id={answer2}
                            className={`answers ${selected === 2 ? 'selected' : ''}`} 
                            onClick={()=> 
                                this.props.selectedScore(2, questionNumber)
                            }
                            >
                        </div>
                        <div 
                              id={answer3}
                              className={`answers ${selected === 3 ? 'selected' : ''}`} 
                              onClick={()=> 
                                  this.props.selectedScore(3, questionNumber)
                              }
                              >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                    <div 
                            id={answer4}
                            className={`answers ${selected === 4 ? 'selected' : ''}`} 
                            onClick={()=> 
                                this.props.selectedScore(4, questionNumber)
                            }
                            >
                        </div>
                        <div 
                            id={answer5}
                            className={`answers ${selected === 5 ? 'selected' : ''}`} 
                            onClick={()=> 
                                this.props.selectedScore(5, questionNumber)
                            }
                            >
                        </div>
                        <Link to={nextQuestion} activeClassName="active">
                            <div 
                                className="answers" 
                                id={answer6}
                                onClick={()=>this.props.calculateScore()}
                            >
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="CircleContainerAlign">
            <Link to={`/`} activeClassName="active">  <div className="homeButton"></div></Link>
                    <div className="circleContainer">
                        <Link to={`/question1`} ><div className="circles" ></div></Link>
                        <Link to={`/question2`} ><div className="circles"></div></Link>
                        <Link to={`/question3`} ><div className="circles"></div></Link>
                        <Link to={`/question4`} ><div className="circles"></div></Link>
                        <Link to={`/question5`} ><div className="circles"></div></Link>
                    </div>
            <Link to={back} activeClassName="active"><div className="back"></div></Link>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Questions;
```

If a user decides to navigate back to question 4 or go to question 5 for example, the timer should reset to 60 seconds and should begin counting down again. If the timer expires, I want to kick them back to the `/` route and reset state.

Answer (score 0):

use setTimeout(function, timeout duration) inside the componentDidMount (although remember setTimeout durations can get blocked by the call stack if 60seconds expires and the call stack is still occupied.

Answer (score 0):

In your componentDidMount function set a timer like this:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.timer = setTimeout(functionWhenDone, 60000)
}
```

This will set the timer and assign a pointer to it to a member variable of your React class.

Then in your componentWillUnmount() function clear the timeout so if a timer is running, and the user navigates away before it's done, you won't get a memory leak.

```
componentWillUnmount = () => {
  clearTimeout(this.timer)
}
```